# Debug in Eclipse : inspect variable -> errors during evaluation

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm working on a piece of Java code and I have a dump problem. I'm doing some debugging and for some reason, when I'm trying to evaluate (watch or inspect) some variables declared inside a method it displays the following error:

```
errors during the evaluation.
```

I don't get it.
I'm using Eclipse 3.7.

For instance, it does the same even for the method parameters (which should be available until the end of the execution of the method).

My `eclipse.ini` file is:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024M
```

Comment: You probably know how to use the debugger, but still.. Are you checking the 'watch expression' when the debugger is still on the 'same' line which contains the 'watch expression'? If you are, can you try checking the 'watch expression' after doing an 'F6'(Step Over) from that line?

Comment: Yes, I allready tryied that. Does not work. I might be the Eclipse JVM size because sometimes on some variables it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was one of my eclipse plugin.
I had several plugins, some code review plugin. I just uninstalled them all and now it works.